# Heyawake - why is this wrong solution

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[image: heyawake question]

Dear people,

Why does this particular android game not accept the solution on the right side?

Rules in the app:
[image: rules]

Comment: @flagged the question because  it is all about software bug...

Comment: @PerpetualJ That's not clear from the outset though. **Questions shouldn't become off-topic just because of their answers.** OP wanted to know if they're solving the puzzle incorrectly or not, which is perfectly within our site's ballpark.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Both solutions are correct. Probably your game doesn't check solution uniqueness well enough.**

The rules of [Heyawake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyawake), as given by your game, are:

1. > A room containing a number must have the designated number of cells painted black. Other rooms may have zero or more cells painted black.

   **Check.** Your change doesn't affect any rooms with numbers in them.
2. > Black cells must not be orthogonally connected.

   **Check.** The only change between your two possible solutions is to move one *isolated* black (or rather grey) cell.
3. > All white cells must be interconnected.

   **Check.** Your change doesn't isolate any white (or rather green) cells.
4. > A line of connected white cells must not connect more than two rooms together.

   **Check.** In fact, your "wrong" solution has *shorter* straight lines of connected white (or in this case green) cells than the "right" one!

It's possible that your game is buggy somehow: it found a solution but didn't check for uniqueness, so in the case of a non-unique solution it's programmed to accept whichever one it knows and reject others as incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, the solution on the right is correct according to all rules of Heyawake. It's likely that that particular app has the "correct" solution hard-coded in, and they didn't check their puzzles for uniqueness well enough.